# Comparing variable to large hex number

Tags: c++, math, unsigned

I'm reading raw binary from a file and want to check if the number is `0xFFFFFFFF`.

```
#define LAST 0xFFFFFFFF

unsigned long data;
//...give value to data
if(data == LAST)
```

This gives different results than if `LAST` was defined as `4294967295` which is the unsigned base 10 representation of `0xFFFFFFFF`. However I noticed the correct results are given if `0xFFFFFFFF` is substituted with `-1`. Why is this?

Comment: Arithmetic conversions...

Comment: @KerrekSB why would it be converted? Isn't it a bit ambigious to know whether or not something is being converted since 0xFFFFFFFF can fit into an unsigned long no problem.

Comment: Built-in operator expressions are only defined on homogeneous types. You *have* to have some way of converting both operands to a common type.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do. I put them both in in one example:

```
   const unsigned long LAST = 0xFFFFFFFFu ;
```

It is bad form to use #define for constants.

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain?

Comment: The U suffix makes the constant unsigned. Using a const, rather than #define forces the value to have a type.